# Remove bibliography title indentation in ClassicThesis with multibib

Tags: bibliographies, indentation, subdividing, classicthesis, multibib

I use the `multibib` package to manage multiple bibliographies within a document adopting the `classicthesis` style. I would like to remove the indentation that is automatically placed before each bibliography title, so that the title results aligned with the list of references.

Any idea how do I do that? Here follows a `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,%
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%
            ngerman,american,%
            ]{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{B}{Books}
\newcites{J}{Journals}
\newcites{S}{Standards}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{american}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


\pdfbookmark[1]{Publications}{Publications}
\chapter*{Publications}

\bigskip

\noindent

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\chapter}[2]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}

\nociteJ{Akyildiz2002}
\bibliographystyleJ{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyJ{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}

\bigskip

\nociteB{Gibson96}
\bibliographystyleB{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyB{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}

\bigskip

\nociteS{IEEESTD1588}
\bibliographystyleS{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyS{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}

\endgroup

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Some Stuff}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapter{Some Other Stuff}
\label{ch:introduction}
\lipsum[4-10]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[3-4]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[33]

\cleardoublepage

\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}} 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\label{app:bibliography}
\nocite{Akyildiz2002,Bulusu2000,Krach2008,Kwak2010} 
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

The `Bibliography.bib` file used to test the above MWE contains the following records:

```
    % This file was created with JabRef 2.8.1.
    % Encoding: UTF8

    @ARTICLE{Akyildiz2002,
      author = {Akyildiz, I. F. and Weilian Su and Sankarasubramaniam, Y. and Cayirci,
        E.},
      title = {{A} {S}urvey on {S}ensor {N}etworks},
      journal = IEEE_M_COM,
      year = {2002},
      volume = {40},
      pages = {102--114},
      number = {8},
      month = aug,
      doi = {10.1109/MCOM.2002.1024422},
      issn = {0163-6804},
      keywords = { protocols, radio networks, sensors CSMA, carrier sense multiple access,
        data processing, health, home applications, hybrid TDMA/FDMA-Based,
        low-cost sensor networks, military applications, multifunctional
        sensor nodes, protocol stack layer, research, sensor networks, wireless
        communications, wireless electronics},
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }

    @ARTICLE{Bulusu2000,
      author = {Bulusu, N. and Heidemann, J. and Estrin, D.},
      title = {{GPS}-less {L}ow-{C}ost {O}utdoor {L}ocalization for {V}ery {S}mall
        {D}evices},
      journal = IEEE_M_PCOM,
      year = {2000},
      volume = {7},
      pages = {28--34},
      number = {5},
      month = oct,
      doi = {10.1109/98.878533},
      issn = {1070-9916},
      keywords = {geophysical equipment, geophysical techniques, microsensors, radio
        direction-finding, radio networksGPS-less low-cost outdoor localization,
        RF communications, connectivity metric method, cost, environmental
        monitoring, experimental results, form factor, localization techniques,
        microsensors, network nodes, periodic beacon signals transmission,
        power constraints, separation distance, soil monitoring, transmission
        range, very small devices, water monitoring, wireless networks, wireless
        sensor nodes},
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }

    @ARTICLE{Dardari2009,
      author = {Dardari, D. and Conti, A. and Ferner, U. and Giorgetti, A. and Win,
        M. Z.},
      title = {{R}anging {W}ith {U}ltrawide {B}andwidth {S}ignals in {M}ultipath
        {E}nvironments},
      journal = IEEE_J_PROC,
      year = {2009},
      volume = {97},
      pages = {404--426},
      number = {2},
      month = feb,
      doi = {10.1109/JPROC.2008.2008846},
      issn = {0018-9219},
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }

    @BOOK{Gibson96,
      title = {{T}he {M}obile {C}ommunication {H}andbook},
      publisher = {CRC Press},
      year = {1996},
      author = {Gibson, J. D.},
      address = {New York},
      edition = {1st},
      month = feb,
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }

    @INPROCEEDINGS{Krach2008,
      author = {Krach, B. and Robertson, P.},
      title = {{I}ntegration of {F}oot-mounted {I}nertial {S}ensors into a {B}ayesian
        {L}ocation {E}stimation {F}ramework},
      booktitle = {{P}roc.\ 5th {W}orkshop on {P}ositioning, {N}avigation and {C}ommunication
        ({WPNC} 2008)},
      year = {2008},
      pages = {55--61},
      address = {Hannover, Germany},
      month = mar,
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }

    @INPROCEEDINGS{Kwak2010,
      author = {Myungkyun Kwak and Jongwha Chong},
      title = {{A} new {D}ouble {T}wo-{W}ay {R}anging {A}lgorithm for {R}anging
        {S}ystem},
      booktitle = {{P}roc.\ 2nd {IEEE} {I}nternational {C}onference on {N}etwork {I}nfrastructure
        and {D}igital {C}ontent ({IC}-{NIDC} 2010)},
      year = {2010},
      pages = {470--473},
      address = {Beijing, China},
      month = sep,
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }

    @BOOK{Rappaport1996,
      title = {{W}ireless {C}ommunications -- {P}rinciples and {P}ractice},
      publisher = {Prentice Hall PTR},
      year = {2001},
      author = {Rappaport, T. S.},
      address = {Upper Saddle River, NJ},
      edition = {2nd},
      month = dec,
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }

    @STANDARD{IEEESTD1588,
      title = {{IEEE} {S}tandard for a {P}recision {C}lock {S}ynchronization {P}rotocol
        for {N}etworked {M}easurement and {C}ontrol {S}ystems},
      organization = {IEEE},
      institution = {IEEE},
      month = jul,
      year = {2008},
      __markedentry = {[paolo:]},
      doi = {10.1109/IEEESTD.2008.4579760},
      journal = {{IEEE} {S}tandard 1588-2008 ({R}evision of {IEEE} {S}tandard 1588-2002)},
      pages = {1--269},
      timestamp = {2012.10.05}
    }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The code you posted is alittle bit too much; please try to minimize it by providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I suppose you refer, in particular, to the content of the `.bib` file. The reason why I posted that code was to save you from spending time to create a minimal `.bib` file. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion. In the future I will try to minimize the code of my MWE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file `multibib.sty` says at some point

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
 \bibsection\parindent \z@\bibpreamble\bibfont\list
```

so `\parindent` is set to zero after `\bibsection` has been used and this produces the undesired indentation (I am not sure if this decision was intentional or it is a bug). To eliminate the indentation, one has to change

```
\bibsection\parindent \z@
```

to

```
\parindent \z@\bibsection
```

Here's one example illustrating how to do it:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,%
            BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%
            ngerman,american,%
            ]{scrreprt}
\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{B}{Books}
\newcites{J}{Journals}
\newcites{S}{Standards}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{suthesis}%
    {\def\thebibliography#1{%
       \newpage
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
       \@ldthebibliography{#1}}}%
    {}%
  \@ifpackageloaded{natbib}%
    {%

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
\parindent \z@\bibsection\bibpreamble\bibfont\list
   {\@biblabel{\arabic{NAT@ctr}}}{\@bibsetup{#1}%
    \usecounter{NAT@ctr}}% %% only changed here to usecounter
    \ifNAT@openbib
      \renewcommand\newblock{\par}
    \else
      \renewcommand\newblock{\hskip .11em \@plus.33em \@minus.07em}%
    \fi
    \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
    \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
    \let\citeN\cite \let\shortcite\cite
    \let\citeasnoun\cite
 }{\def\@noitemerr{%
  \PackageWarning{natbib}
     {Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist\vskip-\lastskip}

      \let\std@thebibliography\thebibliography
      \def\thebibliography#1{%
        \@isnumber{#1}%
        {\ifnum\mb@biblabelwidth=0
          \@tempcnta\c@NAT@ctr %% changed here to c@NAT@ctr
          \ifcontinuouslabels
          \advance\@tempcnta#1%
          \fi
          \std@thebibliography{\@arabic\@tempcnta}%
          \else
          \std@thebibliography{\@arabic\mb@biblabelwidth}%
        \global\mb@biblabelwidth 0
        \fi}%
        {\std@thebibliography{#1}}%
     }%
   }%
   {% else, natbib not loaded
     \let\std@thebibliography\thebibliography

     \def\thebibliography#1{%
        \@isnumber{#1}%
          {\ifnum\mb@biblabelwidth=0
            \@tempcnta\c@enumiv
            \ifcontinuouslabels
            \advance\@tempcnta#1%
            \fi
            \std@thebibliography{\@arabic\@tempcnta}%
            \else
            \std@thebibliography{\@arabic\mb@biblabelwidth}%
          \global\mb@biblabelwidth 0
          \fi}%
        {\std@thebibliography{#1}}%
    }%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{american}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}


\pdfbookmark[1]{Publications}{Publications}
\chapter*{Publications}

\bigskip

\noindent

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\chapter}[2]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}

\nociteJ{Akyildiz2002}
\bibliographystyleJ{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyJ{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}

\bigskip

\nociteB{Gibson96}
\bibliographystyleB{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyB{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}

\bigskip

\nociteS{IEEESTD1588}
\bibliographystyleS{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyS{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}

\endgroup

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Some Stuff}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapter{Some Other Stuff}
\label{ch:introduction}
\lipsum[4-10]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[3-4]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[33]

\cleardoublepage

\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}} 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\label{app:bibliography}
\nocite{Akyildiz2002,Bulusu2000,Krach2008,Kwak2010} 
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]